# sending video issue whatsapp-web.js

Tags: javascript, python, ffmpeg, bots, whatsapp

I'm trying to send an mp4 video as a sticker but i get an error, here's my code

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    const media = MessageMedia.fromFilePath("./vid.mp4");
    client.sendMessage(message.from, media, { sendMediaAsSticker: true });
}
```

but I get this error

```
handleExit(new Error('ffmpeg exited with code ' + code));
                     ^

Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
Error marking filters as finished
Conversion failed!
```

its working with other mp4 files but with this one it doesnt, this is a good working mp4 file I generated with ffmpeg using the concat method.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you execute the ffmpeg command manually?  If so you can rule out "javascript" "python" "bots" "whatsapp" as being factors.

Comment: update- I went online and converted my mp4 to mp4 and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify your chrome.exe path when creating your session.

My solution on windows:

```
   const client = new Client({
        puppeteer: {
            executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
        }
    });
```

See the link: https://wwebjs.dev/guide/handling-attachments.html#caveat-for-sending-videos-and-gifs

also on: https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/1834